# How to make tmux active window more distinguishable?

Tags: tmux

I use tmux as a terminal with tabs. I usually have several windows opened.

[image]

The problem is it's hard to distinguish which window I'm current on. How to configure tmux so that I can distinguish the current window a bit better, rather than a '*' next to the window name.

I'm thinking about invert the bg/fg color for the current window.

Answer (score 4):

OK I have figured out, the following snippet does the job:

```
set -g status-style 'bg=#000000,fg=#ffffff'
set -g window-status-current-style 'bg=#ffffff,fg=#000000'
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right ''
set -g window-status-format "#I:#W"
set -g window-status-current-format "#I:#W"
```

This does something like below:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to set `#[reverse]`, which will invert the colors of fg and bg.

```
setw -g window-status-current-format "#[reverse] #I:#W"
```

Note: `#[default]` will revert to default colors.